# How to remove domainname.com/index.php/photos from URL

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

How to remove domainname.com/index.php/photos from the pyrocms URL. I tried to remove index.php from $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';. But it does not work. Can anyone help please. Is there anything i have to do during the installation time.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use an .htaccess file in the root folder too (if you are using apache or php built-in webserver).

Here is the one I use: https://gist.github.com/taiar/2424263

Here is the reference from the oficial docs: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: I did but am getting 404 error.But whn i add index.php to the url its working

Comment: If you're using apache, make sure it has mod_rewrite enabled.

https://www.google.com.br/search?q=enable+apache+mod_rewrite

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark like this: i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a .htaccess rule

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`